# SQL Select different column values into one row

Tags: sql

I have a table with values something like this:

```
StoreID | ItemID | OpeningClosingBalance | Total
1       | 1      | O                     | 10
1       | 1      | C                     | 20
1       | 2      | O                     | 5
1       | 2      | C                     | 7
```

To the first row is an opening balance of 10 for a specific item. The second row is the closing balance of 20 for that same item. Row 3 is opening for another item, and then is closing balance ect. I would like a query with results displayed as follows:

```
StoreID | ItemID | Openingbalance | ClosingBalance
1       | 1      | 10             | 20
1       | 2      | 5              | 7
```

Can anyone please assist?

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with conditional aggregation:

```
select StoreId, ItemId,
       max(case when OpeningClosingBalance = 'O' then total end) as openingbalance,
       max(case when OpeningClosingBalance = 'C' then total end) as closingbalance
from t
group by StoreId, ItemId;
```